# Lodash create collection from duplicate object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have the following structure:

```
var output = [{
    "article": "BlahBlah",
    "title": "Another blah"
}, {
    "article": "BlahBlah",
    "title": "Return of the blah"
}, {
    "article": "BlahBlah2",
    "title": "The blah strikes back"
}, {
    "article": "BlahBlah2",
    "title": "The blahfather"
}]
```

From the above using an elegant lodash one-liner, I need to create the following structure.

```
var newOutput = [{
    "article": "BlahBlah",
    "titles": ["Another blah", "Return of the blah"]
}, {
   "article": "BlahBlah2",
   "titles": ["The blah strikes back", "The blahfather"]
}]
```

Help as always, is greatly appreciated.. A huge plus for an explanation for how a solution would work.

Comment: `titles` should be array if there is only one record?

Comment: is the property really `'title:'`?

Comment: @NinaScholz.. well spotted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) and then [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) the resulting object to an array of objects.

```
var newOutput = _(output)
    .groupBy('article')
    .map(function(v, k){ return { article: k, titles: _.map(v, 'title') } })
    .value();
```

```js
var output = [{"article":"BlahBlah","title":"Another blah"},{"article":"BlahBlah","title":"Return of the blah"},{"article":"BlahBlah2","title":"The blah strikes back"},{"article":"BlahBlah2","title":"The blahfather"}];

let newOutput = _(output)
    .groupBy('article')
    .map(function(v, k){ return { article: k, titles: _.map(v, 'title') } })
    .value();

console.log(newOutput);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6 arrow-functions,

```
var newOutput = _(output)
    .groupBy('article')
    .map((v, k) => ({ article: k, titles: _.map(v, 'title') }))
    .value();
```

Comment: You have missing the `.value()` resolver to resolve the chain, otherwise you'll get a LodashWrapper instead of the needed value, +1 for the nice approach

Answer (score 3):

A better lodash version could be (using the awesome `chaining` approach)

```
_(a).groupBy('article').map( (x,k) => ({ article: k, titles:_.map(x, 'title')}) ).value();
```

If you want to group by article (so article would be the key, useful for quick lookup)

```
_(a).groupBy('article').mapValues(x => _.map(x, 'title')).value();
```

Comment: Isn't this the same answer? You added an arrow function to the solution, but otherwise only the second part of your answer is new.

Comment: @4castle actually I didn't check yours, but your original answer was a little different, (I think u've used _.chain), even now your's is not correct, since you have missing the .value() resolver at the end

Comment: It's working correctly, but I was also under the impression that `.value()` was only needed if `.chain()` was used. That's why I switched to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

A proposal in plain Javascript

It uses a IIFE (Immediate Invoked Function Expression) for using private variables and for collecting the return values in an array.

Beside that it uses a hash table for the reference to the right array item.

```js
var output = [{ article: "BlahBlah", title: "Another blah" }, { article: "BlahBlah", title: "Return of the blah" }, { article: "BlahBlah2", title: "The blah strikes back" }, { article: "BlahBlah2", title: "The blahfather" }],
    newOutput = function (data) {
        var r = [];
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!this[a.article]) {
                this[a.article] = { article: a.article, titles: [] };
                r.push(this[a.article]);
            }
            this[a.article].titles.push(a.title);
        }, Object.create(null));
        return r;
    }(output);
        
console.log(newOutput);
```

Comment: Thank you, although a lodash example would be great. Just to keep it brief.