# Use Lodash's reduce to sum a collection

Tags: lodash

I have a simple collection:

`[{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]`

**How do I use Lodash's reduce to get the sum of all "a" attributes?**

This seems like a trivial / canonical use, but I can't get the syntax right and surprisingly can't find any docs beyond [Lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce) example.

Using Lodash's docs example, it should be:

`const total = _.reduce([{ a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}], (sum, elem) => elem.a);`

However this returns the value "3" instead of "6'.

Note: I'm specifically asking about the usage of `reduce`. I'm aware of other methods like the one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774763/using-lodash-to-sum-values-by-key).

Comment: reading the lodash's example, `_.reduce([{ a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}], (sum, elem) => sum + elem.a,0)` should work

Comment: here's the [link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1cmst5h/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're forgetting to add `sum` to `elem.a`. Also, you need an initial reduction, otherwise, `sum` will be initialized to `{ a: 1 }`:

```
_.reduce([{ a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}], (sum, elem) => sum + elem.a, 0);
```

You might want to look at `sumBy()` for this too. It's the same reducer, only more concise:

```
_.sumBy([{ a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}], 'a');
```