# Union of 2 arrays with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, union, lodash

I am using lodash 3.10 and i need to unite 2 arrays.

```
[
  {
    "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
    "value": "CMIP"
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": "CMIP@400@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "MES",
    "value": "12"
  }
]
```

and this one that are prety much the same :

```
    [
      {
        "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
        "value": "CMIP"
      },
      {
       name: "CUSTO", 
       value: ">100"
      }
    ]
```

I know theres is a simple way to do it as merge doesnt work in this cas.
Apreciate your help Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740155/lodash-remove-duplicates-from-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique array of objects and merge duplications using lodash or underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877957/unique-array-of-objects-and-merge-duplications-using-lodash-or-underscore)

Comment: Define "unite". Often the best way to communicate what you want in these cases is to complete your example. What should be the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
    "value": "CMIP"
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": "CMIP@400@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "MES",
    "value": "12"
  }
];
var array2 =  [
      {
        "name": "DESIGEMPRESA",
        "value": "CMIP"
      },
      {
       "name": "CUSTO", 
       "value": ">100"
      }
    ];
    
 var merged = _(array1)
  .concat(array2)
  .groupBy("name")
  .map(_.spread(_.merge))
  .value();

console.log(merged);
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```