# Is there a common term/name to Object.__proto__.__proto__ object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, ecmascript-5

I've been playing with and studying the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in Javascript and this subject got me wondering... is there a common name or term to refer to the object that everything else in the end of the prototype chain?

I'm writing a markdown file on a [GitHub repo of mine](https://github.com/brunokrebs/javascript-playground/tree/master/src/es5/prototypes) and there I refer to it as the "God" object. But I'm quite unsure about how this object behaves.

Could I, for example, change the reference on one specific type of Object (lets say, Dog object) to have its own "God", or will I be stuck with this one single "God" object?

Comment: The final prototype from whence all others come is Object.prototype.  You can in theory make an object without a prototype by Object.create(null) and this could be used to form a second prototype chain not originating at Object.prototype - but don't do that, it's not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, well, I wouldn't do it in a real project, I'm just investigating this kind of stuff to better understand Javascript as a whole. Now I have to investigate why what you said is not a good idea. Thanks @PMV

Comment: The reason is that a lot of code will assume objects have certain methods that ultimately are properties on the prototype - particularly .hasOwnProperty() or .toString() - and if you passed an object that didn't inherit from Object.prototype, you would generate an exception in what is otherwise robust code.

Comment: @PMV One way to overcome that would be to call the functions using `Object.prototype`, such as with `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)`

Comment: By the way, don't forget that `Object` is actually a function (it can be used as a constructor), so `Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype`

Comment: Please do not use `__proto__`, it is deprecated. You should use `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object))`

Comment: @PMV One would argue that the code which relies on all objects having `.hasOwnProperty` and `.toString` properties (and their values being certain functions) is broken. It's this mistaken assumption that needs to be fixed, not the code that creates unconventional objects.

Answer (score 2):

The "God" object you're referring to is `Object.prototype`.

```js
console.log({}.__proto__ === Object.prototype);
console.log({}.__proto__.__proto__);
```

If you want to create your own "God" object, use [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

```js
var obj = Object.create(null);
console.log(obj.__proto__);
```

It is commonly used when creating a lookup table, so as to avoid any name conflicts with fields in the prototype, such as `toString`.

```js
function Map() {
  var table = Object.create(null);
  return {
    put: function(key, val) {
      table[key] = val;
    },
    get: function(key) {
      return table[key];
    }
  };
}
var map = new Map();
console.log(map.get('toString'));
map.put('toString', 'test');
console.log(map.get('toString'));
```

Comment: "It is commonly used when creating a lookup table" --- could you elaborate that?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not sure what to elaborate on, but I can show you an example [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38440069/5743988).

Comment: Yep, I see now. Would not be able to infer it from how you explained it in the answer though :-)