# Merge objects in array by value and get count for each

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, count, lodash

Given the following array of objects:

```
myArray = [
  {
    item: 'Item 1',
    material: 'Material1',
    type: 'head'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 1',
    material: 'Material1',
    type: 'head'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 2',
    material: 'Material2',
    type: 'shell'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 1',
    material: 'Material1',
    type: 'head'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 2',
    material: 'Material2',
    type: 'shell'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 3',
    material: 'Material3',
    type: 'support'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 1',
    material: 'Material1',
    type: 'head'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 3',
    material: 'Material3',
    type: 'support'
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 2',
    material: 'Material2',
    type: 'shell'
  }
]
```

I need to combine these by the `item` value with a count so that I get an array that looks like this:

```
var myResultArray = [
  {
    item: 'Item 1',
    material: 'Material1',
    type: 'head'
    count: 4
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 2',
    material: 'Material2',
    type: 'shell'
    count: 3
  },
  {
    item: 'Item 3',
    material: 'Material3',
    type: 'support'
    count: 2
  },
]
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I'm partial to Lodash, but I'm open to other alternatives. With `_.groupBy()` I can get everything grouped together with the item as the object key:

```
var myGrouped = _.groupBy(myArray, 'item');
```

but that only gets me part way there. Searching around here I see a lot of uses of `_.reduce()` (or just plain `.reduce()`) or `_.map()`, but I haven't been able to get my head around exactly how to use them in this case. If I try to use `_.groupBy()` chained with `_.map()` like so

```
var myGrouped = _(myArray).groupBy('item').map(function(item) {
                  // do stuff here
                });
```

the execution doesn't even get to my map function, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: `_.groupBy` followed by `_.map` is the correct solution. Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't even get to my map function"? It works in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38774930/5743988), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38485762/5743988), and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38450804/5743988).

Comment: @4castle I just mean that when I put a breakpoint inside the map() function in my debugger, it didn't stop there. I know it works, so I was assuming I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with this:

```
var groupedData = [];
_(typeData).groupBy('item').forEach(function(value, key) {
  var obj = {};  
  obj.count = value.length;
  obj.type = value[0].type;
  obj.details = value[0].details;
  obj.description = key;
  groupedData.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: Will you please explain what is `_(typeData)` here ?

Comment: `typeData` is the name I gave to the original array of source data (listed at the beginning of the question).

Comment: So for implementing this am I need to add underscore js ?

Comment: No, it uses Lodash. However, other answers above use pure JS without Lodash, so you could try those options, too.

Answer (score 5):

`_.groupBy` chained with `_.map` is the simplest solution. A proper callback function for the `_.map` would be:

```
function (items) {
  items[0].count = items.length;
  return items[0];
}
```

Or you could condense it further with ES6 arrow-functions.

```js
const myArray = [{"item":"Item 1","material":"Material1","type":"head"},{"item":"Item 1","material":"Material1","type":"head"},{"item":"Item 2","material":"Material2","type":"shell"},{"item":"Item 1","material":"Material1","type":"head"},{"item":"Item 2","material":"Material2","type":"shell"},{"item":"Item 3","material":"Material3","type":"support"},{"item":"Item 1","material":"Material1","type":"head"},{"item":"Item 3","material":"Material3","type":"support"},{"item":"Item 2","material":"Material2","type":"shell"}];

const myResultArray =
  _(myArray)
    .groupBy('item')
    .map(items => (items[0].count = items.length, items[0]))
    .value();

console.log(myResultArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without using Lodash, this would create the required array:

```
const res = myArray.reduce((accum, val) => {
  let summary = accum.get(val.item) || Object.assign({}, val, {count:0});
  summary.count++;
  return accum.set(val.item, summary);
}, new Map());

console.log([...res.values()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

using `_.countBy` and `_.uniqBy`

```
var res = _.chain(myArray)
    .countBy('item') // get each item count
    .thru(counts => // counts = {Item 1: 4, Item 2: 3, Item 3: 2}
        _.chain(myArray)
            .uniqBy('item') // get uniq items
            .map(item =>  // set each item count
                _.assign(
                    item, 
                    {count: counts[item.item]}
                );
            )
            .value();
    )
    .value();
```