# Create collection from duplicate object case insensitive keys

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I've structure of array of objects likes this

```
const data = [
  { key: 'One' },
  { key: 'Two' },
  { key: 'Three' },
  { key: 'one' },
  { key: 'two' },
];
```

I want to filter the array in such a way as to get unique objects but also save duplicate keys.

```
const data = [
  { key: ['One', 'one'] },
  { key: ['Two', 'two'] },
  { key: 'Three' },
];
```

I found almost a similar solution here — [Lodash create collection from duplicate object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438645/lodash-create-collection-from-duplicate-object-keys), but I couldn't adapt it to myself.
I can't figure out how to properly filter the entire array without losing performance.

Comment: Can you show what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
data.map(item => {
  let pos = results.findIndex(item2 => {
    let collection = item2.key.map(val => val.toLowerCase())
    let inc = item.key.toLowerCase()
    return collection.includes(inc)
  })
  if (pos == -1) {
    results.push({ key: [item.key] })
  } else {
    results[pos].key.push(item.key)
  }
})
```

Returns this:

```
[
  { "key":["One","one"] },
  { "key":["Two","two"] },
  { "key":["Three"] }
]
```

Here's a codepen I made: [Array Group By](https://codepen.io/paouriel/pen/vYOoeod)