# lodash groupby and sum object properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of Objects that I need to reduce down based on a property and sum the other property. [This solution is pretty much what I'm after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438645/lodash-create-collection-from-duplicate-object-keys), but I need to avoid using `_.chain` as am importing only specific modules.

I've tried using flow, but am not getting any values:

```
const sumBy = require('lodash/fp/sumBy');
const flow = require('lodash/fp/flow');
const groupBy = require('lodash/fp/groupBy');
const map = require('lodash/fp/map');

const list = [
    { property: 'foo', value: 1 },
    { property: 'foo', value: 3 },
    { property: 'bar', value: 2 },
    { property: 'bar', value: 3 },
    { property: 'chu', value: 8 },
];

const foo = flow(
  groupBy('property'),
  map((objs, key) => {
    return {
      property: key,
      value: sumBy(objs, 'value')
    }
  })
)(list)
```

This returns

```
[
    { property: undefined, value: 0 },
    { property: undefined, value: 0 },
    { property: undefined, value: 0 }
]
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this in vanilla es6, I've had a go at it, but not sure how to do the sum.

```
const bar = list.reduce((o, v) => {
    return {...o, [v.property]: v.value}
}, {})
```

Comment: @Ruben's ES6 solution is my preferred way to solve this. But out of curiosity, could anyone answer what I was doing wrong with the lodash flow? When I used the chain method, I got the correct result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following ES6 only solution:

```js
const list = [
    { property: 'foo', value: 1 },
    { property: 'foo', value: 3 },
    { property: 'bar', value: 2 },
    { property: 'bar', value: 3 },
    { property: 'chu', value: 8 },
];

const result = list.reduce((obj, el) => {
  obj[el.property] = (obj[el.property] || 0) + el.value;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Map`.

```js
const
    list = [{ property: 'foo', value: 1 }, { property: 'foo', value: 3 }, { property: 'bar', value: 2 }, { property: 'bar', value: 3 }, { property: 'chu', value: 8 }],
    result = Array.from(
        list.reduce((m, { property, value }) => m.set(property, (m.get(property) || 0) + value), new Map),
        (([property, value]) => ({ property, value }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With lodash

```js
const
    list = [{ property: 'foo', value: 1 }, { property: 'foo', value: 3 }, { property: 'bar', value: 2 }, { property: 'bar', value: 3 }, { property: 'chu', value: 8 }],
    result = _(list)
        .groupBy('property')
        .map((array, property) => ({ property, value: _.sumBy(array, 'value')}))
    ;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be thought of as a [less efficient](https://www.richsnapp.com/blog/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern) but nicer-to-read variant of the answer from Ruben Helsloot.

```js
const sumValues = list => 
  list .reduce ((obj, {property, value}) => ({
    ... obj, 
    [property]: (obj [property] || 0) + value
  }), {})

const list = [{property: 'foo', value: 1}, {property: 'foo', value: 3}, {property: 'bar', value: 2}, {property: 'bar', value: 3}, {property: 'chu', value: 8}]

console .log (sumValues (list))
```